# SQL here - count a distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to figure this question out.

An SQL table called `users` contains data about users. It has columns `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, and `registerdate` (which has type DATE). Write a query that returns the number of users having the first name ‘Sally’ who have registered on each day.*

Here's what I tried.

```
Use database
select count (firstname), registerdate 
from users
where firstname = 'Sally' ;
```

Comment: you need to add a `group by registerdate` at the end.

Comment: `count (distinct firstname)`

Answer (score 1):

```
create table userReg
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    firstname varchar(100) not null,
    lastname varchar(100) not null,
    registerdate date not null
);
truncate userReg;
insert userReg (firstname,lastname,registerdate) values
('Ken','last','2016-01-02'),
('Sally','Higgins','2016-02-02'),
('Sally','Smith','2016-02-02'),
('Sally','Jones','2016-02-04'),
('Sal','lastname','2016-02-07'),
('Jason','last','2016-02-07'),
('Sally','Johnson','2016-04-04');
```

Shown as 1 row 1 column total:

```
select count(distinct registerdate) as theCount 
from userReg where firstname='Sally'; 
+----------+
| theCount |
+----------+
|        3 |
+----------+
```

Shown by date:

```
select registerdate,count(*) as theCount  
from userReg where firstname='Sally' group by registerdate; 
+--------------+----------+
| registerdate | theCount |
+--------------+----------+
| 2016-02-02   |        2 |
| 2016-02-04   |        1 |
| 2016-04-04   |        1 |
+--------------+----------+
```

Use `distinct` inside of `count()`. There were 3 distinct dates with a Sally registration.

Comment: I just realized I answered some other question !

Comment: Not sure. Best deal would be to get some distinctness of the userid or personid. The question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Count(id) FROM users
   WHERE firstname='Sally'
   GROUP BY registerdate

Answer (score 0):

select DATE_FORMAT(registerdate,'%Y-%m-%d') as dt, count(id) from users where firstname='Sally' group by dt;